# Handwriting: Prefixes on German words

Tags: prefix, handwriting

I am trying to read old German handwriting:

[image]

Two words (pater and mutter) have the same prefix.  It looks like "Sau" or "Gau"...the first letter looks like a German capital "S" with a large loop over the top so it looks almost like an American script "P".  The "u"in both the prefix and "mutter" have umlauts.  Can anyone help me interpret this?  Thanks!

Comment: A line above a handwritten *u* is not an umlaut symbol, it just distinguishes it from an *n* (I think).

Comment: Maybe you also add a scan of the other word. Are you sure, that it really is "pater"? This is not a German word. It is latin. You use "Pater" (without any prefix and with uppercase P) in German only for a catholic priest, but I don't know any prefix that you might use with "-pater". I know just compound words like "Jesuitenpater" or "Benediktinerpater" where the fist part is the name of a monastic order. But non of them are used together with "-mutter", and they are all much longer than in your scan.

Comment: This is a very helpful insight.  The paper is very old and creased on the word "pater" or probably it is "vater" as you suggest.  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

That pretty definitely says *Hausmutter*.

The capital letter is a German "H" as in the attached picture off [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift). The "hooks" on top of the "u" are there to make the "u" and "n" easier to distinguish from each other.

I would assume the other word says "Hausvater", then - "Pater" would be a Latin loan word that was used in religious context (monasteries and other organisations), but rather not in a secular one - And normally not combined with "Haus".

[image: Deutsche Kurrentschrift, Von Deutsche_Kurrentschrift.jpg: AndreasPraefckederivative work: Martin Kozák (talk) - Deutsche_Kurrentschrift.jpg, Gemeinfrei, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9873345]

*Hausmutter* and *Hausvater* were sometimes used in former times when more than one family was living in a large household - These two were informally denominated "the bosses" in that household and headed it. Today these "titles" have only survived in boarding schools, children's homes and youth hostels.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you, this is very helpful!  I found a handwriting chart of "Sutterlein". This is closer to the era I am trying to decipher.  This is very insightful.  I think the document indicates some kind of union (a marriage?) because it lists dates (I'm guessing birthdates) of the "Hausvater" and "Hausmutter" with a date in between.

Comment: @cabmurphy the writing is called *S**ü**tterl**i**n* (after its developer), not *_Sutterlein_.

Answer (score 3):

This prefix is

> Haus

so the entire word is "Hausmutter". This is today the same as a "Hausfrau" (housewife) and according to the [Grimm'sche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=Hausmutter) the leader of a big household.